# crash on find() of set container

Tags: c++, templates, stl, crash, set

I have a SyncSet template class which locking on set operations. While I were doing stress test, I got crash. When I check crash output file it seems the reason is something about find function of set container. You can see my template class below and you can reach related crash output in pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/1JzAWxjf

Is there something wrong in my template class may cause such crash? Secondly, is it possbile to OS aborted application because memory limit exceeding or anything like that, is that so then is there a way to check message on OS(windows 7 professional)?

All advices and comments are wellcome and appricated.

Thanks.

```
template <typename T>
class SyncSet
{
public:
    SyncSet() {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&m_lock);
    }

    ~SyncSet() {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&m_lock);
    }

    void Insert(T elem) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        m_set.insert(elem);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
    }

    bool Has(T elem) {
        if (m_set.empty() || m_set.find(elem) == m_set.end())
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    bool Erase(T elem) {
        if (!Has(elem))
            return false;
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        m_set.erase(elem);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        return true;
    }

    size_t Size() {
        return m_set.size();
    }

    void Clear() {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        m_set.clear();
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
    }

private:
    std::set<T> m_set;
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_lock;
};
```

Comment: Can you say anything about the class you used for the template parameter T when you were stress testing this? and if so, care to post it in your question as well ? Also, there are several places in this code that should be passing const references. Finally, `Erase()` need not check `Has()`, and if this is used multithreaded, `Has()` should guarding with the object critical section as well.

Comment: Was your test multithreaded? If yes, then you should do lock/unlock in `Has` function. BTW, you don't need check for `empty` in it

Comment: It was multi-threaded. The pastebin link clearly shows an offending call-stack including `ThreadFunc@Thread@CompanyInternal`

Comment: @WhozCraig maybe it was the only thread ))

Comment: @borisbn Then I would expect to find wWinMainCRTStartup in the call stack, per SOP for VC-runtimes.

Comment: +1 @WhozCraig , but also like to add  if you're worried about memory limit being exceeded, you should be trying to catch an exception from the insert.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry for not mentioning about T type, it is integer in my case. And yes, this is multithreaded. Thanks for your adviceses and points.

Comment: @mgundes I *strongly* suggest that you craft (or find pre-canned) a simple class that latches the critical-section by-reference on construction, optionally allows method-function access to unlatch it, and above all, guarantees it is unlatched in the destructor. Called a scope-lock, it will not only make your code more elegant, but also guarantee an exception throwing around your LeaveCriticalSection doesn't perma-hang all your threads.

Comment: @WhozCraig, scope-lock as you explain will be better, right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't thread-safe, as although you protect all writes to the set within the critical section, you don't protect the read in Has().

So, for example, the stress-test can be halfway through the Has() call when another thread erases the entire set.

Note that a critical_Section is a gate, it gets checked only at other EnterCriticalSection() calls, and the find within Has doesn't use it, so the code there will not be stopped when another thread is within the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

Consider contriving a different sort of lock, to increase parallelism.

Let's look at a table of what we are currently doing, and what we're thus allowed to do:

```
                        Trying to:
                   |  Read  |  Write
           --------|--------|----------
           Nothing |  yes   |  yes
Currently  Reading |  yes   |  no
Doing:     Writing |  no    |  no
```

Any thread that wants to read can do so, as long as no other thread is writing, and any thread that wants to write can only do so if no other thread is accessing the resource.

Notice that without some additional work not described here, this solution will have a starvation condition: a thread trying to write may have to wait a long time for all of the reading threads to finish, since as long as any one thread is reading, the writing thread will continue to block, but other reader threads will be able to acquire their locks.

This may be totally overkill for what you're doing, but if you expect that your project will be sufficiently distributed that many threads may try to read concurrently, it might be worth looking into.  I understand that it doesn't directly answer your question, but it was too long for a comment, and I figured there was a chance it would be useful.

Comment: thanks, this will be v1.0 and the next step will be performance optimization. At that time we will consider this issues as well.